# USB modem not detecting

Tags: usb

How can I use USB dongal based datacard in Ubuntu 15.04.

My OS is not detecting that UBS modem.

Thanks
PRadeep

Answer (score 0):

You can try detecting your USB devices by opening up a Terminal, and entering the following commands: **lsusb** or **usb-devices**